# how to parameterise SOAP request in Postman?

Tags: postman

I have to perform the SOAP request validation with the below WSDL:

http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL

I have to parameterise the below post request for [string] in Postman.

Can you please let me know how to perform paramterisation?

POST Request

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <Body>
    <CountryCurrency 
      xmlns="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
        <sCountryISOCode>[string]</sCountryISOCode>
    </CountryCurrency>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you talking about putting data in the SOAP Header?

Comment: yes  I am talking about header. I need to get paramterise [string] to IN ,USA or AU for the tag <sCountryISOCode>[string]</sCountryISOCode>

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_header.htm

Answer (score 1):

- In Postman select `POST` method put
  http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso
- Go to `Body` put this code
  `<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo"><x:Header/><x:Body<web:CountriesUsingCurrency><web:sISOCurrencyCode>EUR</web:sISOCurrencyCode></web:CountriesUsingCurrency></x:Body></x:Envelope>`
- `Reponese` 
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><m:CountriesUsingCurrencyResponse xmlns:m="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo"><m:CountriesUsingCurrencyResult><m:tCountryCodeAndName><m:sISOCode>AT</m:sISOCode><m:sName>Austria</m:sName></m:tCountryCodeAndName><m:tCountryCodeAndName><m:sISOCode>AX</m:sISOCode><m:sName>Åland Islands</m:sName></m:tCountryCodeAndName></m:CountriesUsingCurrencyResult></m:CountriesUsingCurrencyResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`
- SEE POSTMAN ::  [open postman and click this](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/befc4742e8b246c82a6e)